# Yii2 + Angular - получение Id вновь созданной записи в приложении Angular

Tags: yii2, rest, angular

Я пишу приложение backend Yii, frontend Angular. Сейчас я занимаюсь формой добавления новой записи в БД у меня появился следующий вопрос. Id вновь добавленной записи в базу данных будет известна только после отправки формы - она возвращается из сервиса следующим образом:

```
public function create(CandidateCreateDTO $dto)
{
    $id = $this->candidates->nextId();
    $dto->id = $id->getId();
    $candidate = Candidate::create(
        $id,
        $dto->getName(),
        $dto->getInfo(),
        $dto->photo,
        $dto->comment,
        $dto->location,
        $dto->getContacts(),
        $dto->getSkills(),
        $dto->getDocuments()
    );
    $this->candidates->add($candidate);

    return $id->getId();
}
```

Для того - чтобы воспользоваться этим Id(например сделать POST запрос на роут candidates/{id}/documents-candidate,candidates/{id}/skills-candidate, candidates/{id}/contacts-candidate для создания прикрепленных документов, скиллов и контактов кандидата) - мне нужно как то его получить в приложении Angular? Как это правильно сделать? Код моего экшена Create в контроллере:

```
 public function actionCreate() {
    $params['lastname'] = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('lastname');
    $params['name'] = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('name');
    $params['fathername'] = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('fathername');
    $params['location'] = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('location');
    $params['salary'] = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('salary');
    $params['current_company'] = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('company');
    $params['current_position'] = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('position');
    $params['skills'] = null;
    $params['documents'] = null;
    $params['photo'] = null;
    $params['wish'] = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('wish');
    $params['comment'] = \Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('notes');
    $this->dto->load($params);
    $this->service->create($this->dto);
}
```

DTO:

```
public function load(array $params)
{
    $this->id           = ($params['id']) ?? '';
    $this->name         = ($params['name']) ?? '';
    $this->lastname     = ($params['lastname']) ??'';
    $this->fathername   = ($params['fathername']) ??'';
    $this->location     = (is_numeric($params['location'])) ? $params['location'] : null ;
    $this->salary       = (is_numeric($params['salary'])) ? $params['salary'] : 0;
    $this->company      = ($params['current_company']) ?? null;
    $this->position     = ($params['current_position']) ?? null;
    $this->wish         = ($params['wish']) ?? '';
    $this->birth        = ($params['birth']) ?? '';
    $this->contacts     = ($params['contacts']) ?? [];
    $this->skills       = (is_array($params['skills'])) ? $params['skills'] : [];
    $this->comment      = ($params['comment']) ?? '';
    $this->photo        = ($params['photo']) ?? '';
    $this->comment      = ($params['comment'] ?? '');
    $this->documents    = (is_array($params['documents'])) ? $params['documents'] : [];
}
```

Comment: Отправляешь данные на создание и в ответе получаешь id. Либо можно всю структуру получить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!